# Add video URL, with live preview option

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am creating a form which allows people to enter a video url. Standard input form, to accept a URL like:

```
http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=1299927595688205543
```

I would like to add a button (within the form, which says something like [preview video]). Basically that button/link appends the link they entered into the input field, to this code:

```
<a href="http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=1299927595688205543&lightbox[width]=610&lightbox[height]=360" class="lightbox">google video</a >
```

This is to be available prior to form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form id="video_upload_form" action="">
    <label for="video_input_box">Video URL</label>
    <input type="text" id="video_input_box" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Add Video" />
</form>

<p><a href="#" id="video_preview" class="lightbox">Preview Video</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function(){
    $('#video_upload_form').submit(function(){
        var video_url_params = '&lightbox[width]=610&lightbox[height]=360';
        var video_url = $('#video_input_box').val() + video_url_params;
        $('#video_preview').attr('href', video_url);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Also here it is as a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Treffynnon/CEMpT/

You will need to do some validation on the URL supplied by the user before putting it into the preview link, but I will leave that part up to you as you have not asked for help with it in your question.

Comment: so what do I put in the input field ? @Treffynnon
Thanks for the quick response by the way

Comment: I am struggling to figure out how to add this within a form.

Comment: Thanks, but the link is not being passed to the preview link: I get <pre><p><a href="#" id="video_preview" class="lightbox">Preview Video</a></p></pre>
I guess thats what you mean by url validation ?

Comment: strike that, lol wicked it works. But can we code it so we dont need to click [add video] button. Just want it to parse via the preview video link

Comment: You can take look at jQuery's `$.keyup` event to get the url as they type in the input. I think this is what you mean anyway.

Comment: Kinda. I was looking to have NO submit button. User enters video url in input field, then when they click OUT of that input field, the URL is appended to your script, so that when they click the link, the lightbox opens up. Any suggestions ( we are 80% there ) lol

Comment: Cheers mate, awesome, we now have live preview :) yayyyy thanks so much.