# How to preview video after typing the video url on a form without pressing the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Please i need your help!

I am working on a website where users can embedd their videos just by posting their video url. I want the video to show in an iframe or in the same page immediately after typing the video url without clicking on the submit button. This will enable the user to see the preview of their video before hitting the submit button.

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">

<input  type='url' name='urladdress' >

</form>
```

Assuming the url is:

```
$url= $_POST["urladdress"]
```

I know this can be achieved with `javascript`, `jquery` or `ajax`. But I don't know how! Please I really need your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: At least show us what have you tried so far

Comment: url like youtube video ?

Comment: yes. youtube, openload, xvideos and so on

Comment: did u try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198511/add-video-url-with-live-preview-option with some modification, it could be what you need

Comment: i suggest you look for "jquery oembed plugin"

Comment: @ Jax Teller it is not working. I have tried it. besides, i dont want the video to pop up!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a change event on the input field. If there is anything changed in the field, a preview iframe will be created if it doesn't exist, or the "src" attribute will update.

An example with jQuery:

```
$('input[name="urladdress"]').on('change', function() {
    if($('#video-preview').length) {
        $('#video-preview').attr('src', $(this).val());
    } else {
        $(this).after($('<iframe id="video-preview" width="854" height="480" src="' + $(this).val() + '" />'));
    }
});
```

This example simply add a iframe after the input field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I really appreciate! how can i implement the change event? I am not good in javeascript! thks..

Comment: In the example code, `$('input[name="urladdress"]').on('change', function(){})` 
 will find the input field with specified name attribute, defines a change event handler with `function(){}`, and bind the handler to the input element. In the example code, a iframe element is created or updated, if there is any change in the input field